# What does it mean for $\mathcal{C}$ to be a $\mathcal{D}$-module, when $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ are categories?

Tags: category-theory, modules, representation-theory

If $\mathcal{C}$ is a module over a category $\mathcal{D}$, what does this mean? I looked around on line but couldn't find a definition.

My guess is that this means there is a functor $\mathcal{D}\to\operatorname{End}(\mathcal{C})$ from $\mathcal{D}$ into the category of endofunctors on $\mathcal{C}$? And so objects of $\mathcal{D}$ give endofunctors on $\mathcal{C}$, and the arrows in $\mathcal{D}$ give natural transformations of endofunctors, all encoded in a functorial way?

Comment: It depends. If $D$ is a monoidal category it means $C$ has been equipped with a monoidal functor $D \to \text{End}(C)$.

Comment: An old terminology for presheaves calls "modules" the functors $C \to Set$. So, if $D$ is monoidal and $C$ is $D$-enriched, a $D$-module can also mean a functor $C\to D$.